About the notation for TEM waves
I just came across this article where the term "$\mathrm{TE}_{101}$ microwave mode" is mentioned. Other than the basics of TEM waves which I learned in Griffiths, this is the first time I have ever seen the use of the subscript.
I am curious whether this kind of notation is used generally, for TE, TM, and TEM waves, and I would like to have an explanation for what the notation means.

It refers to the frequency $\omega_{n,l,m}$ of the mode

These are waves in a cubic cavity with a mixture of Dirichlet and Neuman boundary conditions, so there are three integers $l,m,n$ labeling sine or cosines  such as $\sin(n \pi x/L_x)$. Which integer is which depends on how the $E$ field is oriented.
